# Moving and returning a mutable pointer

Tags: memory, rust, ownership

I am working through [this](http://aml3.github.io/RustTutorial/html/02.html) Rust tutorial, and I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Implement a function, `incrementMut` that takes as input a vector of integers and modifies the values of the original list by incrementing each value by one.

This seems like a fairly simple problem, yes?

I have been trying to get a solution to compile for a while now, and I'm beginning to lose hope. This is what I have so far:

```
fn main() {
    let mut p = vec![1i, 2i, 3i];
    increment_mut(p);

    for &x in p.iter() {
        print!("{} ", x);
    }
    println!("");
}

fn increment_mut(mut x: Vec<int>) {
    for &mut i in x.iter() {
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

This is what the compiler says when I try to compile:

```
Compiling tut2 v0.0.1 (file:///home/nate/git/rust/tut2)
/home/nate/git/rust/tut2/src/main.rs:5:12: 5:13 error: use of moved value: `p`
/home/nate/git/rust/tut2/src/main.rs:5  for &x in p.iter() {
                                                  ^
/home/nate/git/rust/tut2/src/main.rs:3:16: 3:17 note: `p` moved here because it has type `collections::vec::Vec<int>`, which is non-copyable
/home/nate/git/rust/tut2/src/main.rs:3  increment_mut(p);
                                                      ^
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `tut2`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I also tried a version with references:

```
fn main() {
    let mut p = vec![1i, 2i, 3i];
    increment_mut(&p);

    for &x in p.iter() {
        print!("{} ", x);
    }
    println!("");
}

fn increment_mut(x: &mut Vec<int>) {
    for &mut i in x.iter() {
        i += 1i;
    }
}
```

And the error:

```
Compiling tut2 v0.0.1 (file:///home/nate/git/rust/tut2)
/home/nate/git/rust/tut2/src/main.rs:3:16: 3:18 error: cannot borrow immutable dereference of `&`-pointer as mutable
/home/nate/git/rust/tut2/src/main.rs:3  increment_mut(&p);
                                                      ^~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `tut2`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I feel like I'm missing some core idea about memory ownership in Rust, and it's making solving trivial problems like this very difficult, could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Bear in mind that that set of notes is for a version of Rust that’s about a year old, which is *very* old for Rust. You will doubtless have noticed various of the differences.

Comment: Is there somewhere that you could recommend for good rust tutorials, other than [rust-lang.org](http://rust-lang.org)? Some of the tutorials on there even seem to be outdated [using ~ and @ rather than `box`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/guide-lifetimes.html#taking-the-address-of-fields)

Comment: That link is for 0.9, as the URL reveals. Start at http://doc.rust-lang.org/ and you'll be fine, getting up-to-date information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

1. `increment_mut(&p)`, given a `p` that is `Vec<int>`, would require the function `increment_mut(&Vec<int>)`; `&`-references and `&mut`-references are completely distinct things syntactically, and if you want a `&mut`-reference you must write `&mut p`, not `&p`.
2. You need to understand patterns and how they operate; `for &mut i in x.iter()` will *not* do what you intend it to: what it will do is take the `&int` that each iteration of `x.iter()` produces, dereference it (the `&`), copying the value (because `int` satisfies `Copy`, if you tried it with a non-`Copy` type like `String` it would not compile), and place it in the mutable variable `i` (`mut i`). That is, it is equivalent to `for i in x.iter() { let mut i = *i; … }`. The effect of this is that `i += 1` is actually just incrementing a local variable and has no effect on the vector. You can fix this by using [`iter_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter_mut), which produces `&mut int` rather than `&int`, and changing the `&mut i` pattern to just `i` and the `i += 1` to `*i += 1`, meaning “change the `int` inside the `&mut int`.

You can also switch from using `&mut Vec<int>` to using `&mut [int]` by calling [`.as_mut_slice()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_mut_slice) on your vector. This is a better practice; you should practically never need a reference to a vector as that is taking two levels of indirection where only one is needed. Ditto for `&String`—it’s exceedingly rare, you should in such cases work with `&str`.

So then:

```
fn main() {
    let mut p = vec![1i, 2i, 3i];
    increment_mut(p.as_mut_slice());

    for &x in p.iter() {
        print!("{} ", x);
    }
    println!("");
}

fn increment_mut(x: &mut [int]) {
    for i in x.iter_mut() {
        *i += 1;
    }
}
```